# Google Play Services "There is no linked app associated with this client ID"

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I know there are lot of answers for this question ,i have tried all of them , i am still unable to find solution.

I have published the app on play store and now i am trying to add leaderboard in my game using google play services.I have added a new game in play store console(In Google Play Services Section) and completed all the steps.I have linked the app in console and it automatically authorize the game.After that i have added the tester account.
i am using release build to test the game.But i am still getting this error "There is no linked app associated with this client ID"

I have tried deleting the linked app 3-4 times and added again as suggested in other answers.

I have added app id in my manifest file.

please suggest me if i am missing any step.

Thanks

Comment: I faced similar issue.  The reason is because we only added the SHA1 key of our debug keystore and our signing key we used to sign the app.  But once we upload the bundle to google playstore, play store creates another key and it has its own SHA1 key, which should be added in credentials section of Play Games configuraiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue by Re-Linking the Game for 3-4 times and added same game 2-3 times in the Linked Apps.I don't how it works but leaderboard is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you followed all the steps in Setting Up Google Play Games Services[1].

Were you able to auto signin with clientID, before adding leaderboard in your game?
Did you add release Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) according to that document[1] , as you are using release build?

[1] https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

Comment: Yes i followed the steps.And i am able to log in using the clientId , the problem starts when i try to submit score and try to show the leaderboard.
From the Google Play Console i don't know how to specify SHA1 key(to add release SHA1) because it picks by default when i try to link the app.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the documentation of [setting up google play services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) step by step  and then make sure your client id in your **app manifest**  and the client id on the on the **console**  are matching 
[image]

You can find your client id on the linked app page on your console account as shown in the in the picture

Comment: I followed the [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) steps.
yes client Id is same in app manifest and console.